# c# picturebox matrix index

Tags: c#, matrix, indexing, picturebox

So I created a matrix of pictureboxes and I want to get the index of every picturebox, the "i" and "j" of the picturebox that was clicked in that matrix.

Here I created the matrix and the click method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                place[i, j] = new PictureBox();
                place[i, j].Parent = table;
                place[i, j].Size = new Size(100, 100);
                place[i, j].Location = new Point(100 * i + 20 * i, 100 * j + 20 * j);
                place[i, j].Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                place[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(p_Click);
            }

 void p_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var current = sender as PictureBox;
    }
```

How do I get that "i" and "j"?

Comment: You could do it in reverse, and use the location to determine which PB was clicked.

Comment: Well, the thing is that I want to create another int matrix and I want to put a number int that second int matrix at the position of the clicked picturebox.

Comment: You can just store the int's from @ChrisF's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You know the location that was clicked.

Make sure that it's relative to the top left of the image, then simple integer arithmetic will give you the cell that was clicked:

```
int i = location.X / 100;
int j = location.Y / 100;
```

I notice that you've got an offset (a border) so you'll have to take that into account as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the index `3*i+j`, say, in the `PictureBox.Tag`, and retrieve it in the handler.